# Terragrunt - variables declarations

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I have a two directories: in first one I'm keeping modules (basically terraform template configurations) in the second one I'm keeping terragrunt modules implementations. In the second one there is a terragrunt hcl file with `inputs` inside (one for every particular project). So far I declared variables in modules directory (in `variables.tf`) but I don't like that as variables change depending on the implementation (project). So keeping all variables (for all projects) in the modules dir seems to be not the best idea.

My question is: how can I declare those variables on the terragrunt (aka implementations) level? Is a `generate` function way to go?

Comment: Please share your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HCL files to store you variables on Terragrunt level. For instance, keep you project level variables in `config.hcl`:

```
locals {
    env = "dev"
}
```

And then load it in your `terragrunt.hcl`:

```
locals {
    config = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("config.hcl")).locals
    env = local.config.env
}

inputs = {
    env = local.env
}
```